# can i use select within create command or use triggeer ; help me please sql plus oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

i want when i insert account_sh value calculate automatically the new total of all columns in new and all previous records of account_sh

like that

```
id  account_sh   percentage  total
001    50             1        50
```

when i insert the another record it will be****

```
id     account_sh    percentage    total
001    50             0.25            200
002   150             0.75            200

create table main_sh (
    id_sh number (9),
    account_sh number not null,
    percentage_sh number(*,15) generated always as  (account_sh/total_sh),
    total_sh number generated always as select sum(account_sh) from main_sh);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to do it would be by adding a trigger to your table which says something like:

```
IF INSERTING THEN:
    IF :new.total_sh is NULL THEN
        SELECT sum(account_sh) from main_sh into total;
        :new.total_sh := total;
    END IF;
END IF;
```